# Page number position with fancyhdr and memoir oneside

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, fancyhdr, book-design

I am trying to have a one sided layout for a book in `memoir` (that is: each page shall have the same right and left margins) but I want the header and the footer to have different margins as well: the header shall be always on the left on a smaller left margin while the page numbering, appearing in the footer, shall be on the extreme right for odd pages and extreme left for the even ones.

So far, so good, I was able to use `fancyhdr` (and the `ifthenelse` package) to mimic this behaviour. However I am not able to define a principled margins for the page numbers: what I am trying to accomplish is to have the left margin equal the right margin as if they were on a two sided layout.

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\setmainfont{Plantin MT Pro}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[head=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}


\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\footerfont}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont\setmainfont{Founders Grotesk}}
\newcommand{\headerfontii}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\uppercase{#1}}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyheadoffset{16mm}
\fancyfootoffset{17mm}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[LO]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\colorbox{White}{\raisebox{6mm}[0cm][0cm]{\headerfontii\rightmark}}}{\colorbox{White}{\raisebox{6mm}[0cm][0cm]{\headerfontii\leftmark}}}}

\fancyfoot[L]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\colorbox{White}{\raisebox{-23mm}[0cm][0cm]{\footerfont\thepage}}}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\colorbox{White}{\raisebox{-23mm}[0cm][0cm]{\footerfont\thepage}{}}}}


\setstocksize{225mm}{160mm} %Finale
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0cm}{0cm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{26mm}{42mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{25mm}{42mm}{*}
%\settypeblocksize{152mm}{92mm}
%\setlrmargins{5mm}{*}{*}

%\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout

\title{Italic. Identità Nazionale Regionale, nuovi codici visivi di rappresentazione}
\author{}
\date{} % Delete this line to display the current date

% \markboth{\thesection}{pisello}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont
\RaggedRight

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: xelatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

And this is what it looks like: as you can see the margin on the left of the first page number is smaller than the one on the right of the number in the second page. What is a way to accomplish this?
[image]

**UPDATE**:
What I want is to have the red margins to have the same length (the smaller one that is on the left page) and different from the green margin, which is the text margin (this is alredy accomplished by setting the `fancyheadoffset` parameter)

Comment: you should not use `fancyhdr` with `memoir`, I'm not quire sure what it is you are trying to do. Your code is very confusing.

Comment: thanks but different margins are my problem

Answer (score 1):

This can be used as a starting point. We use a `twoside` setup that are then tricked into looking like a `oneside` layout

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% just to show they are vastly different
\setlrmarginsandblock{2cm}{4cm}*
\checkandfixthelayout
% trick
\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{m}
\makeoddhead{m}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeevenhead{m}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{m}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{m}{\thepage}{}{}

\copypagestyle{n}{m}
\makeoddhead{n}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{n}{}{}{}

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{n}

\pagestyle{m}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using fancyhdr since I need to have the header and footer margins different from the ones for the text (see picture)

Comment: All of that can be configured as well. I still do not understand what you are trying to do, that the images does not help much. What does those boxes have to do with everything?

Comment: the boxes are a trick to make the header rise over the margin I set with memoir. can I specify the different margins with memoir only? could you please provide a sketch of it?

Comment: It is still not clear what so ever what you are attempting. So I don't know what to make a sketch of.

Comment: You can see in the picture that the header 'PREMESSA' has a smaller left margin than the text box (the same goes for the number '4' in the footer). I am using fancyhdr to specify those margins against the ones I specified for the text box with memoir

Comment: I updated the question with a colored picture, hope it helps, thanks again